# Contacts.app: Failed to update account

Tags: contacts.app

## Symptoms

I was having trouble with my El Capitan Macbook Pro running slow, especially when using syncing contacts. To troubleshoot, I erased my drive and reinstalled El Capitan. Once I entered my Apple ID and set up Internet Accounts, the problem returned, even though I hadn't deviated from the base install in other ways.

## Diagnosis Data

### Console messages

```
11/23/15 4:06:14.115 PM com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService[421]: [Accounts] Current connection, <NSXPCConnection: 0x7fc15151cf80> connection from pid 2807, doesn't have account access.
11/23/15 4:06:14.117 PM com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService[421]: [Accounts] Current connection, <NSXPCConnection: 0x7fc15151cf80> connection from pid 2807, doesn't have account access.
11/23/15 4:06:14.118 PM com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService[421]: [Accounts] Current connection, <NSXPCConnection: 0x7fc15151cf80> connection from pid 2807, doesn't have account access.
11/23/15 4:06:14.120 PM com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService[421]: [Accounts] Current connection, <NSXPCConnection: 0x7fc15151cf80> connection from pid 2807, doesn't have account access.
11/23/15 4:06:14.123 PM findNames[2807]: [Accounts] Failed to update account with identifier 4938371A-DC8E-4523-BA40-D26D167F4889, error: Error Domain=ABAddressBookErrorDomain Code=1002 "(null)"
11/23/15 4:06:14.145 PM findNames[2807]: [Accounts] Failed to update account with identifier 9D4385DA-AA0D-4028-9679-A307DBAFC958, error: Error Domain=ABAddressBookErrorDomain Code=1002 "(null)"
11/23/15 4:06:14.145 PM findNames[2807]: [Accounts] Failed to update account with identifier C4CAE0DC-22CC-4C16-91BE-0E63ABD4B700, error: Error Domain=ABAddressBookErrorDomain Code=1002 "(null)"
11/23/15 4:06:14.145 PM findNames[2807]: [Accounts] Failed to update account with identifier A36263CB-A19D-4C2B-89EA-83C1FFF4E24B, error: Error Domain=ABAddressBookErrorDomain Code=1002 "(null)"
11/23/15 5:06:44.118 PM AddressBookSourceSync[2830]: *** -[NSRecursiveLock unlock]: lock (<NSRecursiveLock: 0x7fd5127efeb0> '/private/var/folders/fp/hgp922cd3nq3vx89fc1pjq_00000gn/T/.AddressBookLocks/_Users_merc_Library_Application Support_AddressBook_Sources_C4CAE0DC-22CC-4C16-91BE-0E63ABD4B700_Metadata_.MetaData.lock_lock') unlocked when not locked
11/23/15 5:06:44.118 PM AddressBookSourceSync[2830]: *** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.

11/23/15 6:05:57.483 PM com.apple.AddressBook.InternetAccountsBridge[623]: Checking iCDP status for DSID 183765062 (checkWithServer=0)
11/23/15 6:05:57.492 PM com.apple.AddressBook.InternetAccountsBridge[623]: XPC Error while checking if iCDP is enabled for DSID 183765062: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.cdp.daemon was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.cdp.daemon was invalidated.}
11/23/15 6:05:57.493 PM com.apple.AddressBook.InternetAccountsBridge[623]: Daemon connection invalidated!
11/23/15 6:05:57.496 PM com.apple.AddressBook.InternetAccountsBridge[623]: [AOSAccounts] : [__49-[ACAccountStore(iCloudAccount) icaAppleAccounts]_block_invoke] : accountsWithAccountType returned error: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)"
11/23/15 6:06:07.535 PM com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService[421]: [Accounts] Current connection, <NSXPCConnection: 0x7fc151406a70> connection from pid 1022, doesn't have account access.
11/23/15 6:06:07.536 PM com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService[421]: [Accounts] Current connection, <NSXPCConnection: 0x7fc15140a740> connection from pid 546, doesn't have account access.
11/23/15 6:06:07.536 PM sharingd[546]: [Accounts] Failed to update account with identifier C4CAE0DC-22CC-4C16-91BE-0E63ABD4B700, error: Error Domain=ABAddressBookErrorDomain Code=1002 "(null)"
11/23/15 6:06:07.536 PM DataDetectorsDynamicData[1022]: [Accounts] Failed to update account with identifier C4CAE0DC-22CC-4C16-91BE-0E63ABD4B700, error: Error Domain=ABAddressBookErrorDomain Code=1002 "(null)"
11/23/15 6:06:07.575 PM com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService[421]: [Accounts] Current connection, <NSXPCConnection: 0x7fc151713340> connection from pid 438, doesn't have account access.
11/23/15 6:06:07.576 PM CalNCService[438]: [Accounts] Failed to update account with identifier C4CAE0DC-22CC-4C16-91BE-0E63ABD4B700, error: Error Domain=ABAddressBookErrorDomain Code=1002 "(null)"
11/23/15 6:06:13.156 PM com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService[421]: [Accounts] Current connection, <NSXPCConnection: 0x7fc15160c1d0> connection from pid 2251, doesn't have account access.
11/23/15 6:06:13.156 PM Airmail 2[2251]: [Accounts] Failed to update account with identifier C4CAE0DC-22CC-4C16-91BE-0E63ABD4B700, error: Error Domain=ABAddressBookErrorDomain Code=1002 "(null)"
```

*Note: By the time I got to writing this, I'd installed Airmail 2, but this error existed before I did so.*

### Console report

```
Process:               AddressBookManager [1751]
Path:                  /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/Versions/A/Helpers/AddressBookManager.app/Contents/MacOS/AddressBookManager
Identifier:            AddressBookManager
Version:               9.0 (1679)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           AddressBookManager [1751]

…
System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        3  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.utility-qos.overcommit

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000007fbc0313df8
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0x7fbc0313df8:
    Process Corpse Info    000000010f8d0000-000000010fad0000 [ 2048K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  
--> 
    STACK GUARD            0000700000000000-0000700000001000 [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack guard for thread 1

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: objectID
…
```

Let me know what additional information I can post. This is the kind of question in which one can't know exactly what to ask. What's going on here? I have several accounts. How can I know which ones these console errors refer to? How can I make it all better?

Comment: It's 11 months after I posted, and I'm still having this issue. I have account update-related issues logged by Airmail 3, Fantastical 2, Contacts.app, `accountsd`, `sharingd`, and `kernel`. These same programs are hogging CPU cycles enough to make my computer nearly unusable.

If you have any tips on how to make progress, even if it's not a full answer, it would make a significant difference for me and for Lorin.

Comment: One of the accounts that repeatedly has issues is "account with identifier 8316C7CE-CE09-48FC-BED3-42B266AC1200", but I have many accounts. How can I know which one that is?

Answer (score -1):

I'm looking for a solution also and I've read that deleting all your accounts from your Internet Accounts settings can help. I can't guarantee this will help YOU, though.

Comment: We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think your answer is the best way to address the OP's question.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review -